# Two identical servers, one performing much worse (even during BIOS POST)

Tags: hardware

I have two identical machines (Supermicro X8DTU-F motherboard with 2 Xeon E5520's, DDR3 ECC RAM, and no hard drives and no extra PCIe devices). However, one of these machines is extremely slow -- it takes about 10-20 times longer to get past BIOS/POST, and, once it boots, it is unusably slow (both machines boot an identical CoreOS configuration over PXE).
I have reset the BIOS settings on both of them, and I can also confirm that both machines have the same BIOS version.

I have also replaced the RAM with known working sticks, but this made no difference.

Therefore, it looks to me like this is a hardware issue. However, I have never encountered a hardware issue that caused a machine to slow down like this before, and I cannot find any obvious hardware error reports by the system (nothing seems to ever fail, it just takes forever to complete).

Do you have any ideas about what might be wrong with this machine and is there anything specific I could try to check?

Thank you!

Comment: Check the CPU cooling/temperature.

Answer (score 1):

Modern servers, like the one you mention, have support for IPMI. This is an umbrella of multiple technologies that allows to monitor a server:

- Remote access: SOL - serial over LAN (IPMI 1.5), [IP-KVM (IPMI 2)](https://www.supermicro.com/Products/nfo/SMS_SD5.cfm), virtual floppy, virtual CD
- hardware event log
- sensors monitoring: temperature, fan speed, voltages

See also: https://www.supermicro.com/products/nfo/ManagementSoftware.cfm

You need to see the event log of the server and check if you have any errors. Contact manufacturer if the motherboard is still under warranty.

On your motherboard you have 2 computers: the main server and [BMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface#Baseboard_management_controller), a small computer used to implement the remote part of IPMI. BIOS software is independent of the IPMI/BMC one. So upgrading the BIOS will not upgrade BMC/IPMI. You can also have separate firmware updates for power supply, CPU microcode, storage controllers, RAID controllers, HBA, ethernet cards.

Benchmark which component is slow. Check also utilization and saturation. CPU, memory, disk, network.

If the server is too old and the warranty is expired do not spend too much time. Replace it. It might be cheaper than the pay for your time spent debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I've checked the sensor readings and event log through the IPMI interface, and found only very minor differences between the working machine and the bad one: On the bad one, the intrusion detection switch is broken, and permanently shows that an intrusion has been detected (can't clear it, not even putting a jumper wire where the switch goes). Could this be triggering some sort of CPU throttling to prevent overheating when the cover is off? The temperature readings look normal, however. Also, there are a bunch of low Vbat warnings. I'll run some benchmarks next.